# Conversion of collection to int array

Tags: java, collections

I want to display a graph and for displaying that i need integer values.I get this from my code

```
    Collection c = Sort.values();
```

Is there any way that i convert collection in such a way that i get integer values?i get this when i print the collection c

```
    [64770, 26529, 13028, 848, 752, 496]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming the values are of type `Integer`, you can try this:

```
Collection c = Sort.values();
Integer[] a = (Integer[])(c.toArray(new Integer[c.size()]));
```

Comment: For efficiency purposes, can this answer be changed to get a `int[]` instead of `Integer[]`?  And was this for an older version of Java before autoboxing?

Comment: @SimonT "can we use `int[]`?" No, not in Java. "was this for Java before autoboxing?" There's no autoboxing in this code (it's not necessary here). Collection could be made generic, but that is not necessary either.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (Integer value : c) {
    int i = value.intValue();
    //do something with either value or i
}
```

Comment: Too complicated. Due to autoboxing, you can immediately write: `for (int i : c) {` - no intValue - gymnastics needed.

Comment: Well that was only to make clear what happens and wasn't sure if wanted an Integer or int. Hence my comment in the code about "do something with either value or i"

Answer (score 2):

*The question was:* conversion to **int** array
`Integer[]` can not be assigned to `int[]` or vice versa

```
int[] array = c.stream().mapToInt( i -> i ).toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
Integer[] yourArrayVar = yourCollectionVar.toArray(new Integer[0]);
```

java just needs to know what kind of array to produce.