# Convert Collection to int[] array

Tags: java, arrays, collections, toarray

There are two existing methods named `getDetails(...)`. One expects a minimum of one mandatory parameter and the other expects a collection (doesn't validate the content/size of the collection).

The problem is that the collection is sometimes passed as empty and according to my business case, I always expect a minimum of one value, to be passed. So, I need to make that method `private`, which accepts Collections.

```
// There are two params, to make sure that at-least one is passed by the caller

public static CustomerContext getDetails(int id, int... ids) { 
   Collection<Integer> idCollection = Instream.of(ids).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
   if(!idCollection.contains(id)){
       idCollection.add(id);
   }
   return getDetails(idCollection);
}
```

I'm planning to make the below method scope to `private` so that the callers would not call this method with Zero attributes.

```
public static CustomerContext getDetails(Collection<Integer> idCollection) {
    return getDetails(idCollection,false);
}
```

One of the caller methods is passing Collection object to `getDetails` like below,

```
CustomerContext.getDetails(id.getDetails().values());
```

The id.getDetails() is as below,

```
public Map<Id,Integer> getDetails(){
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(details);
}
```

I'm looking for a way to convert the collection `id.getDetails().values()` into `int[]` for passing to `getDetails(int id,int... ids)` instead of calling `getDetails(Collection<Integer> idCollection)`.

I could cast the collection to `Integer[]` as below,

```
(Integer[])id.getDetails().values().toArray()
```

I did not find a way to cast Collection to `int[]`.

Any suggestions would be of great help.

I already referred to some of the existing questions but did not succeed to solve my issue:

[Conversion of collection to int array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664698/conversion-of-collection-to-int-array)

[Convert java.util.Collections to Integer array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26967716/convert-java-util-collections-to-integer-array)

Comment: toArray should solve the issue what is happening by your side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Collection to Integer[]

When you need to get a result of type `Integer[]`, you have to provide a function as an argument while calling `toArray()`, there's no need to apply casting (*if you're not passing a parameter* `toArray()` *returns an array* `Object[]`).

```
Integer[] arr = id.getDetails().values().toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

#### Collection to int[]

There's no way convert a Collection of `Integer` type or an array `Integer[]` into an array `int[]` directly. It's not possible to obtain one from another simply by doing casting, these types are not compatible.

You have to iterate over the source and populate the newly created `int[]` array. It can be done either "manually" using a loop, or in a more convenient way with streams, the overall approach doesn't change.

That's how it can be done using Stream API:

```
int[] arr = id.getDetails().values().stream() // Stream<Integer> - stream of objects
    .mapToInt(Integer::intValue) // IntStream - stream of primitives
    .toArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't *cast* `Collection<Integer>` to `int[]`, but you can *create* the array:

```
int[] values = id.getDetails().values().stream()
  .mapToInt(n -> n)
  .toArray();
```

---

An aside... this code:

```
if (!idCollection.contains(id)) {
    idCollection.add(id);
}
```

May be changed to just:

```
idCollection.add(id);
```

because `idCollection` is a `Set` and that's how sets work. It matters not that it's *declared* as a `Collection`; it *is* a `Set`.